# Portable offline virus scanner for a low-memory system

Tags: windows, offline, portable, antivirus

I have low system memory and work in a pretty safe environment so don't feel it wise to have a big antivirus running in background all the time. I also have multiple systems so a **portable** AV that I can place in all of them through a USB stick would be the nicest option for me.

I have tried ClamWin Portable, but it is far too slow to scan and its virus detecting skills is on the lower side.

Other antivirus solutions mentioned here and there in discussion forums are less known and I am not sure whether to try them or not.

Answer (score 3):

When someone doesn't like ClamWin Portable, I recommend **[Comodo Cleaning Essentials](http://www.comodo.com/business-security/network-protection/cleaning_essentials.php)** It's a bit simpler and less feature-rich than Clamwin, but its scanning is arguably superior.

A few bulletpoints...

- It's from a [well-reviewed](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2415202,00.asp) vendor that's been around [for a long time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comodo_Group).
- It can be installed on a USB drive and run standalone.
- It has frequent updates to its definition tables.

Comment: Thanks for that info, another software I found in that class is [Emsisoft Emergency Kit](http://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/eek) but it is 210 mb download, much larger than CCE. I will try it later.

Comment: As expected, CCE requires virus definitions to be downloaded, now it is same as Emsisoft.